# Testing @Retryable and @Recover methods in Spring Boot + Mockito

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, spring-test, spring-retry

For one class e.g. called Class A, I call an external api (with exceptions and I have mocked the class). In Class B, I have a method that calls Class A's method with the potential exceptions that could occur. Class B has the @Retryable and @Recover method. I have Class A as a mock object and Class B as a spy. When I mock Class A to throw an exception and I verify the times it has been called - I get the correct maxAttempts called. However, when I try to check and verify the method for recover or retryable I get:

```
UnfinishedVerificationException
..
Missing method call for verify....
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to verify these method calls?

Comment: can you show the code ? if you are recovery method is getting executed after retry exhausted then why do you want to verify recovery again ?

Comment: as far of my knowledge recovery method will call only once after retries exhausted, i would suggest to check return value to make sure recovery is executed

Answer (score 1):

Those methods can't be mocked because they they are final methods created by spring-retry using a CGLIB proxy.